# Commitments and snarks: overflow over a finite field

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

Let

**x = 100 - initial balance**

**M = 1,000,000,000**

transfer amount final balance **M+x**

**E(p-M) + E(M + x) = E(p - M + M + x) = E(p + x) = E(x)**

producing correct proof of the fact that the final balance minus the initial balance is equal to the transfer amount
where **E(x) = x*g**,

**g** - generator of ellipt.curve,

**p** = ellipt. group order

and a similar question, does it arise somewhere in **zk-snorks**? if this problem exists, how is it solved? if not, why not?